# Filter Table data using Ajax in Codeignitor

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm not able to filter table data using Ajax. When I select BANK CREDIT from drop down it should fetch employee details with modeofpay(table column) as "BANK CREDIT" and when I select NEFT it should display employee details with modeofpay(table column) as "NEFT". As of Now nothing happens when i select drop down.

Controller:

```
public function filter($key = '')
{
  $this->load->helper('url');

  if ( $key == 'BANK CREDIT' ) {
    $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model');
    $data = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->getCredit($key);
  } 
  else 
  {
    $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model');
    $data = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->getNeft($key);
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function getCredit($key)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE modeofpay = '$key'";
  $data = $this->db->query($sql);
  return $data->result_array();   
}

public function getNeft($key)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE modeofpay = '$key'";
  $data = $this->db->query($sql);
  return $data->result_array();   
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var paymode = $("#mode").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:url:'<?php echo base_url("JcMeetingExpense/filter/key/") ? 
               >'+paymode,
      data:"key="+paymode,
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(data){
        $("#viewjcexpense").html(data);
      },
      error:function(XMLHttpRequest){
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<select name="mode" id="mode" >
  <option value="BANK CREDIT">CREDIT</option>
  <option value="NEFT">NEFT</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what error u got in console?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. Table remains blank even after selecting. @Rp9

Comment: have you tried replaceWith() function insted of html()?

Comment: You can try to access direct function using url may be this thing will be help to debug

Comment: No I haven't, how does replaceWith() works with this? @ShubhamAzad

Comment: and what does the request return as a response in dev tools? this is troubleshooting 101.

Comment: Hey it's working well when I access using url... but how to make this work using AJAX@SureshSuthar

Comment: Have you added the any <div> with the ID Attribute of viewjcexpense in view?

Comment: No I haven't@Dolar

Comment: Please paste you whole view code here. Also you have got the result data in ajax response?

Comment: `getNeft` and `getCredit` are looking very much alike ...

Answer (score 0):

is your `onchange` event working ? 
let's check with

```
$("#mode").change(function(){
alert(1);
});
```

if when u selected an option would be show the alert that's mean ur event working ,

now if that's working fine let's try to playing with ajax and do little recode,  here i used post method

[ VIEW ]

```
$("#mode").change(function(){
     $.ajax({
                type  : 'POST',
                url   : '<?=base_url(); ?>JcMeetingExpense/filter/',
                data  : { key : $("#mode").val() },
                success : function(data){
                       console.log(data);//let's check on console what's response is 
                    }
                });
 })
```

[CONTROLLER]

```
public function filter()
{
  $this->load->helper('url');


    $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model');
    $dataKey = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->get_data_by_key();


  echo json_encode($datadataKey);
}
```

[MODEL]

```
 public function get_data_by_key()
    {
     //do post here let's say
     $key = $this->input->post("key");
// i looked your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection 
/*      $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE modeofpay = '$key'"; 
      $data = $this->db->query($sql);
      return $data->result_array();   */
      //so let's use query builder 
      $this->db->select("*");
      $this->db->from("employee");
      $this->db->where("modeofpay",$key);
      $q = $this->db->get();
      return $q->result_array();
    }
```

now check response in console

Comment: hey i'm stuck with the onchange event. it's not working.I'm Not getting the alert message @Aiden

Comment: I did some corrections in my script, after doing this i got the alert so the event is working fine now.... but i'm not getting the response on console.

Comment: <script>
$(function () 
{
    $('#mode').on('change', function()
    {
      $.ajax({
               type  : 'POST',
                url   : '<?=base_url(); ?>JcMeetingExpense/filter/',
                data  : { key : $("#mode").val() },
                success : function(data){
                       console.log(data);//let's check on console what's response is 
                    }
                });
    }
});
</script>

Comment: ok, no response in console ? `var_dump($key)`; die(); put in model in get_data_by_key method , press f12 > go to network find and click `filter/ `

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("body").on('change','#mode',function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:url:'<?php echo base_url("JcMeetingExpense/filter/key/") ? 
               >'+paymode,
      data:"key="+paymode,
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(data){
        $("#viewjcexpense").html(data);
      },
      error:function(XMLHttpRequest){
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

try this script instead of your previous script

i have changed `$("#mode").change(function(){});` with  `$("body").on('change','#mode',function(){});`